# How to convert folder to jar in window

Tags: jar

I want to convert folder to jar,
is there any command for cmd in window  or good online converter to convert it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

a jar file is for a java program, if you need to compress a folder into a single file, try zip. You should be able to do it in windows.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14200/windows-compress-uncompress-zip-files

You can install 7zip if you need a command line client.

Comment: I converted executable jar file into folder that contain css ,js,xml files ,i want to re convert it into again  jar  to re deploy